# Has anyone created a Label, Divider, or Instructions FieldType for Umbraco Contour?

Tags: umbraco, contour, umbraco-contour

I am surprised there isn't an Umbraco Contour field out-of-the-box that lets form editors write RichText or at least plain text instructions in-between the form fields, so that form authors can add more detailed instructions scattered throughout a form.

Does anyone know if this exists?

I found this suggestion in 2011: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/22661-Place-plain-text-in-contour-form

My first attempt, I put together a custom field for Contour 3.0.21 and Umbraco 7.1.x, but I am not too keen on how the form results table now has an empty column. Instead, I would prefer that the content is placed in the form without creating a column in the result table, and also without emailing an empty field in the "Send Email" workflow email.

Comment: Also, there are these examples, but are they updated enough? http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-contour-shared-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried taking a look at the **Contour Contrib** project for Contour?

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/contour-contrib

There is a Label fieldtype there that I believe does what you're looking for. If it does, you can get the source for that project and use that to create more field types that meet your needs.  I hope that helps!

Comment: I did see that and wasn't sure if it would work for Umbraco 7 but it did apparently. I might have had to add the "view", but it was easy enough.

Comment: So, I suppose to be a better answer, would be to include the changes that needed to be made to work with Umbraco 7.

Comment: I think this is what I added to FieldType.label.cshtml... The model: @model Umbraco.Forms.Mvc.Models.FieldViewModel... and the code: @Model.AdditionalSettings[1].Value